# List of 2008 NACE Rev 2 codes

Tags: european

Am looking for a simple list of the NACE 2008 rev 2 codes (The European classifications for economic sectors).  The official publication is [here](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/3859598/5902521/KS-RA-07-015-EN.PDF), but is there an easily accessible list of the actual codes available anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Found..  Doesn't contain the aggregations but it's easy to scrape the detailed codes from here:

http://www.cso.ie/px/u/nacecoder/index.asp

Answer (score 0):

RDF would be more suitable to processing, consider using file from Eurostat directly: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/ramon/rdfdata/nace_r2.rdf.

Comment: this link appears to have expired..  "The requested URL /eurostat/ramon/rdfdata/nace_r2.rdf was not found on this server."